# systemd :: conditional Requires if contents of a file match

Tags: systemd

I have a service (lets say it is called xrootd) which would require the start of another service (called cmsd) if there is a certain declaration in the common config file. Is there a way to add a Requires if the declaration is present in conf file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution I can think of is to write a [generator](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.generator.html) which symlinks `cmsd.service` into `xrootd.service.requires/`, perhaps like this (untested):

```
# /etc/systemd/system-generators/xrootd-requires-cmsd
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ ^CertainDeclaration ]]; then
        requiresCmsd=true
        break
    fi
done
if [[ $requiresCmsd ]]; then
    mkdir -- "$1/xrootd.service.requires/"
    ln -s -t "$1/xrootd.service.requires/" /usr/lib/systemd/system/cmsd.service
fi
```